# What is the purpose of re-setting AUTO_INCREMENT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, innodb

I have encountered the fact that some people, after performing deletion of rows from a table, also reset the **AUTO_INCREMENT** for the primary key column of that table to re-number all the values as if they started from 1 again (or whatever the initial starting point).

My question is, is there a specific reason for doing this, other than just preference? As in, is there any detrimental impact on the database or future queries if you do not reset the auto-increment and just leave it as-is? If there is, could somebody provide an example where it would be necessary to reset **AUTO_INCREMENT**?

Thanks!

Comment: resetting AUTO_INCREMENT is asking for trouble if you need JOINS within MySQL  
chance is that you JOIN the wrong records together when you reset the AUTO_INCREMENT..i advice you not the reset AUTO_INCREMENT to prevent holes in MySQL.

Comment: Messing with the auto-increment is really bad practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resetting auto-inc is an uncommon operation. Under normal day to day work, just let it keep incrementing.

I've done reset of auto-inc in MySQL instances used for automated testing. A given set of tables is loaded with data over and over, and deletes its test data afterwards. Resetting the auto-inc may be the best way to make tests repeatable, if they're looking for specific values in the results.

Another scenario is when creating archive tables. Suppose you have a huge table, and you want to empty out the data efficiently (not using DELETE), but you want to archive the data, and you want new data to use id values higher than your old data.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable_new LIKE mytable;

SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME='mytable';

ALTER TABLE mytable_new AUTO_INCREMENT = /* value + 10000 */;

RENAME TABLE mytable TO mytable_archive, mytable_new TO mytable;
```

The above series of statements allow you to shuffle a new empty table into place atomically, so your app can continue writing to the table by the name it's used to. The auto-inc value you reset in the new table should be a value higher than the max id value in the old table, plus some comfortable gap to avoid overlap during the moments between the statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, and for giving an example of how it can be useful!

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is ever *necessary* to reset auto_increment, unless you are running out of values.

One case where auto-increment is often reset is when all the rows are deleted.  If you use `truncate table`, then the auto-increment value is reset automatically.  This does not always happen with `delete` without a `where` clause, so for consistency, you might want to reset it.

Another case is when a large insert fails, particularly if it fails repeatedly.  You might not want the really large gaps.

When moving tables around you might want to keep the original id values.  So, essentially, you ignore the auto-increment on inserts.  Afterwards, though, you might want to set the automatic value to be consistent with other systems.

In general, though, resetting the auto-increment is not recommended.

Comment: If you are running out of values, you probably need a more serious solution.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, I've seen this behavior.  And from what I observed, it's *not* due to a technical reason - it's closer to OCD.

Some people *really* don't like gaps in the ID column - they like the idea of it smoothly increasing by 1 for each record.  The idea that some manual data manipulation they're doing screwing that up isn't pleasant - so they go through some hoops to make sure they don't cause gaps in the numbers.

But, yeah, this is a terrible practice.  It's just asking for data integrity problems.

Comment: I like the "OCD" reason.  (But I doubt if I would use it when supplying an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Reseting the auto increment usually helps in terms of organization, you can see no gap between id 6 and 60 if the rows between have been deleted.

However, you should be carefull about working with resetting auto-increments, because most likely, your code will depend on specific id's to fetch certain information.

In my opinion, just truncate the whole thing after your tests and seed the database with the correct information. If it's production, let it run wild and free, it could cause more harm and no beneficial output

Comment: Assuming that autoincrement ids will be sequential is *very* dangerous. They will not be contiguous if you you use concurrent transactions. They will not be contiguous if you are running MySQL replication.

Comment: Correct, allow me to edit my post with your comment, it is a very important note!

Comment: Thanks for the answer and warning - I'm glad that I asked before following this practice. And to answer your earlier question, I do indeed play WoW but not on Turalyon. :D

Comment: [OFF-TOPIC] Damn, I got a guild mate called lanaya :P wait, maybe it's doomhammer? Know a name of Panquecas? I got no way of sending you a message :/

Answer (score 1):

As per comment on abr's answer, assuming that auto-increment ids are contiguous (or even sequential) is not just a bad idea, it is a dangerous one.

There may be good reason for deliberately creating gaps in the allocated ids if you intend to patch the data at a later point (e.g. if you have restored from an old backup and expect to recover some of the missing data but need to restore a service asap) or when you migrate from a single active server to multiple master nodes. But in these scenarios you are setting the counter to higher value than currently used - not resetting it back to the start.

If there is a risk that you are going to wrap around the numbers, then you've probably [picked the wrong data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) for your auto-increment attribute - changing the data type is the right way to fix the problem, not deleting data and resetting the counter to 0.

Comment: There are _many_ actions that can create gaps, such as `DELETE`, `ROLLBACK`, `INSERT IGNORE`, etc.